# Seaborn: Get color/hue from factorplot/facetgrid

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Is there a way to get the color that is assigned to each group when calling Seaborn's [`factorplot`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html%20factorplot)? E.g. can I get the color of `"one"` in the following plot? Thanks!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["one"]*4 + ["two"]*4 + ["three"]*4 + ["four"]*4 + ["five"]*4,
    "value": np.random.randint(0, 10, 20),
    "num": range(0, 4)*5
    })
ax = sns.factorplot(x="num", y="value", hue="name", data=df, kind="point", legend_out=False)
legend = plt.legend(fontsize="x-large")
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Instead of trying to get the color from the figure, specify the color you want to plot with.

Comment: Thanks @mwaskom, how exactly would I go about doing that? Can I say something like `{"one":"green", "two":"blue"}` etc and pass that to `hue`?

Comment: Yes that would be one way.

Comment: @mwaskom, I'm sorry, `hue` doesn't seem to expect dictionaries, could you throw me a bone here? I'm getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` when saying `hue={"one": "green", "two": "green", "three": "green", "four":"green", "five": "green"} `

Comment: Thanks, @mwaskom, passing to palette works.

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want?

```
In [84]: legend.parent.get_lines()[0].get_color()
Out[84]: (0.2980392156862745, 0.4470588235294118, 0.6901960784313725)
```

Comment: This looks promising, thanks @MaxU! Any idea how I can extract e.g. "one" from the list returned by `get_lines()`? And FWIW, I don't understand the prompt about asking a question either.